# Negative validation not working in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular6, angular7

I have the following HTML *Angular* tags, which need to trigger a validation error when there is a negative value entered in any of the groups of textboxes (dynamic array).

```
<tr *ngFor="let order of configWT.get('wtFormArray').controls; let i =index" formArrayName ="wtFormArray">

<input natinput type ="number" [formControlName]="i" id="wtage" ngModelChange="updateWTage(i)" required>
```

**ngOnInit**

```
ngOnInit():void
{
this.configWT = this.formBuilder.group({
wtFormArray: new FormArray(['',[Validators.min(0)]])
}
```

Here is the error condition which is working for required validation, but not working for min validation.

**Working**

```
<nat-error *ngIf="configWT.get('wtFormArray').at(i).hasError('required'))" 
    error test
    <nat-error>
```

**Not Working**

```
<nat-error *ngIf="configWT.get('wtFormArray').at(i).hasError('min')" 
    error test
    <nat-error>
```

Here is the DOM

[image: DOM]

I am feeling like I am comparing min value with an array which may be causing this problem? please help!

Comment: Your min validator is tied to the form group and not the form control. Have you tried adding to the form control input element? I can't quite remember but it should be min/requiredMin or something along those lines

Comment: min max in html input is just for length not for value

Comment: for number type, it should be the value. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp

Comment: i already added min and max, but not working still

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use `minlength` for minimum validation, it will be easier, because for `new FormArray` it's not correct to add validation in such way

```
<input natinput type ="number"
  [formControlName]="i"
  id="wtage"
  ngModelChange="updateWTage(i)"
  required
  minlength="4">


<nat-error *ngIf="configWT.get('wtFormArray').at(i).hasError('minlength')"> 
    error test
<nat-error>
```

Comment: not working , i tried the same , not error